# Online Linux Server

Tags: centos, cloud

I'm wondering if there is any online Linux VM solutions available for purchase/subscription with a public IP?

I'd like to pay a monthly/yearly fee for root access to an IP address of a Linux (CentOS) VM in the cloud which I could play with.

I'm looking for an 'out-of-the-box' online server which would be available for SSHing onto, setting up cronjobs to run scripts, database hosting, website hosting etc.

I have a CentOS VM running locally in VirtualBox but ideally I'd like to run scripts 24/7 and be able to access the server from any computer via SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) is what you're looking for. They provide a lot of out-of-the-box virtual private servers with full root access as well as SSH.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Have you used this before? Is it possible to have direct access to the terminal and full accessibility to the system ?

Comment: @tehjoker yes, I have some experience of setting up a Digital Ocean VPS. Yes, it allows you to treat your server as a real one with full accessibility to the system directory tree from the /.

Comment: @tehjoker good luck :)

Comment: @tehjoker please accept my answer if it's what you're looking for in order to close the question.

Comment: I've went with an AWS solution - I've heard alot about this in the media recently but wasn't sure if I could get access to an actual terminal on a web server.. I always expected it to be webhosting using FTP! (whoops).. Thanks for the push in the right direction - wasn't sure these solutions were available !

Answer (score 2):

There are many of those, the location of the company and the servers vary and so does the prices (and I assume the quality), just a few:

- [Bytemark](https://www.bytemark.co.uk)  (my favourite)
- [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com) (as already mentioned in another answer)
- [OVH](https://www.ovh.ie)
- [DreamHost](https://www.dreamhost.com)

In general you want to search for VPS (Virtual Private Server).

Answer (score 1):

After a short time googling, I've went with an AWS solution.

They offer a free 12 month trial period on a small, basic solution.

Within minutes I'm up and running on a Redhat VM connected via SSH (Term2) on my Mac.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-12-23-223 ~]$ cat /etc/system-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
```

https://aws.amazon.com/

Comment: That is also an option :) good luck!

Comment: Thanks alot - I'd also recommend you check it out - free to get up and running! Time to learn how to scrape sites 24/7.... thanks for the help!

Comment: just in case you need some dev labor - I'm open to some data extraction contracts on Upwork.

Comment: That's what brought me here looking for this solution. Just started on upwork recently myself! Do you have any opensource scripts you would like to share? I always learn quicker from example !

Comment: not a big deal but I have vagrant base box provision repo and a fix for an Upwork Team App as it often fails to connect to the server. Take a look (maybe you find something useful) https://www.github.com/ddnomad/vconfwrap